# ruby on rails if statement always returns true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, conditional-statements

**controller code:**

```
  def create

    if current_user.id != params[:friend_id]
      @return = { :curr_user_id => current_user.id, :params_id => params[:friend_id], :debug => 1 }
    else
      @return = { :curr_user_id => current_user.id, :params_id => params[:friend_id], :debug => 2 }
    end

    render :json => ActiveSupport::JSON.encode( @return )

  end
```

so `current_user.id` is **1** and `params[:friend_id]` is being passed via an ajax call and its value is also **1**

the problem is that it always returns true when it should return false in this case... is there anything that has to do with the number 1 being parsed as string instead of integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

params are **always** strings, use:

```
if current_user.id != Integer(params[:friend_id])
```

I don't recommend `to_i`, look why:

```
"abc".to_i     # => 0 which is unexpected
Integer("abc") # => raises error, which is fine
```